# Setting a pointer, remaining NULL

Tags: c, null-pointer

I'm trying to implement a linked list and I have come upon a very stubborn and frustrating problem. Here is the relevant code.

```
Node* current = list->head;
Node* previous = malloc(sizeof(Node*));
previous = NULL;
while(current != NULL){
    if(current == NULL){
        printf("current is null");
    }
    last = current;
    current = current->next;
    if(last == NULL){
        printf("last is null");
    }
}
```

Now the problem with it is it is printing

"last is null"

frequently but doesn't print out

"current is null"

once. If current is not null and i set last = current then why does last stay null?

Thank you for any and all insights

Comment: This code is horribly broken in many trivial ways.

Comment: In a while loop that executes as long as `current`is not `NULL`, when do you think the `if(current == NULL)`will be true?

Comment: well i figure there's something going on that I currently don't understand because I'm setting last to current (which isn't NULL) yet last is still NULL. I put the print statements in to try to better understand the situation :(

Comment: One thing that amazes me is how this allegedly manages to print "last is null".

Comment: dude I wish it weren't the case but that's what i'm dealing with

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't want to use `sizeof(Node*)` which will allocate the size of a pointer (32-bit / 64-bit / something else depending on the platform). It is pointless since you can and already do define a pointer using `Node* previous`.

Secondly, expression in `while()` checks if current is not equal to `NULL`. If current is equal to `NULL` it will simply exit the loop so your `if(current == NULL)` comparison won't execute.

You can make that comparison valid if you put `if(current == NULL)` after `current = current->next;`. However, if `last is null` is printed, something else is also completely flawed with your code because `current` has to be null before `last`. It is surprising it is not giving a segmentation fault or something.

Comment: Thanks man, unfortunately with this fix the same problem still exists. When I set last = current, last is still NULL This is my biggest issue right now

Comment: @BrianDillmann it seems to be impossible because then it would also have to say `current is null`.

Comment: @BrianDillmann Question does not have enough data. The loop won't have any problems after you do the changes I said. You probably failed to properly define the list inferring from `malloc`ing a pointer.

Comment: "*which will allocate the size of a pointer (long)*" -- There is no necessary relationship between the size of a pointer and the size of `long`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Right, it is on linux but it is not a requirement. Editing.